# Есть ли человек на изображении

Tags: opencv

Пытаюсь создать фильтр, который бы быстро определял есть ли на картинке человек или нет для последующей обработки изображения. Учитывая что нужна скорость, нейронка (вроде той что используется `openpose`) не подходит, так как работает довольно долго и затрачивает много ресурсов. К тому же мне не нужно определять скелет (и какие либо другие точки), а просто отфильтровать изображения. Нашел два решения этой проблемы:

1) С помощью вейвлетов Хаара (в репозитории `opencv` имееются уже предобученные объекты) - `haarcascade_fullbody.xml`

2) используя `HOG` дескриптор.

К сожалению (`detectMultiScale`, по крайней мере при дефолтных настройках, прописывал только входное изображение и массив прямоугольников для возвращаемого значения) получаются крайне низкие результаты: на большинстве изображений с людьми (один человек в полный рост на большей части изображения) тела не были найдены, а среди тех, где были - много ложных срабатываний. Есть ли другие способы? Или можно как-то существенно улучшить вышеперечисленные?